# Tietze Extension Theorem ,,

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If we have X a normal space, C a closed subspace of X, Y a completely regular space, and $f:C \rightarrow Y$ a continuous function. How do we show that f has a continuous extension $F: X \rightarrow Z$, where Z is a compact Hausdorff space containing Y as a subspace.

I was given the hint to use Tietze Extension theorem, but still remains stuck, could more hints be given to tackle the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, why did you delete your other question? The one about maximal compactification?

Comment: Hi, I have come up with the answers for the question that I am asking previously. Thought I could just delete them away. :)

Comment: I'm just asking because I was about to post an answer, but never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $\Phi$ be the set of all continuous functions from $Y$ to $[0,1]$. For each $\varphi\in\Phi$ let $I_\varphi$ be a copy of $[0,1]$, and define

$$h:Y\to\prod_{\varphi\in\Phi}I_\varphi:y\mapsto\langle \varphi(y):\varphi\in\Phi\rangle\;.$$

Show that $h$ is a homeomorphism of $Y$ onto $h[Y]$.

Now you can let $Z=\prod_{\varphi\in\Phi}I_\varphi$ or, if you want to be a little more elegant, you can let $Z=\operatorname{cl}h[Y]$; in this case $Z$ is the [Čech-Stone compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Construction_using_the_unit_interval) of $Y$. Note that for each $\varphi\in\Phi$, $\varphi\circ f$ is a continuous function from $C$ to $[0,1]$, so you can apply the Tietze extension theorem to it.

Comment: HI, but if we apply the Tietze extension theorem, we wil only have a continuous $F: X \rightarrow [0,1]$, how would we ensure we have a continuous function $F: X \rightarrow Z$?

Comment: @user90831: It’s hard to say much more without simply giving you the proof, but I’ll try. For each $\varphi\in\Phi$ let $\widehat\varphi$ be a continuous extension of $\varphi\circ f$ to all of $X$; now use the functions $\widehat\varphi$ to define a continuous extension of $f$.

Comment: @user90831: You're welcome!